# Change the layer format to a different image resolution

Tags: pytorch

There is a class where everything is set to 32x32 image format Taken from here

```
class Net(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 5) # here I changed the image channel from 3 to 1
            self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
            self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 64, 5)
            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 5 * 5, 120)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
            self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 22) # here I changed the number of output neurons from 10 to 22

        def forward(self, x):
            x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
            x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
            x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
            x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
            x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
            x = self.fc3(x)
            return x
```

How to change all this under resolution 96 to 96? Channel 1 (grayscale)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At resolution *32x32* the output of `conv2` is shaped `(1, 64, 5, 5)`. On the other hand, if the input is at resolution *96x96*, it will be `(1, 64, 21, 21)`. This means `fc1` needs to have `28_224` input neurons.

```
>>> self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 21 * 21, 120)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`nn.LazyLinear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LazyLinear.html) which will infer this number for you, based on the first inference.

```
>>> self.fc1 = nn.Linear(120)
```